# How could I replace a substring in a string, and get the full string with the replaced substring in it?

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring

How could I replace a substring in a string, and get the full string with the replaced substring in it?

```
string ex1 = "Example1";
string output;

for (int i = 0; i <= ex1.Lenght; i++)
{

    if (ex1.Substring(i, 1).Contains("1")
    {

        output = ex1.Substring(i, 1).Replace("1", "!");
    } // output is here ! but i want the complete string with the Replaced substring, like "Example!"
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your question? Can you show what's your desired result?

Comment: Why do you use a loop and substrings at all? `Replace` should be enough.

Comment: it really isn't clear to me *why* we're doing all the substring work here; what is it that you're *actually trying to achieve* here? what are the intended input/output? This *looks* like a simple single replace or single regex, no?

Comment: output = ex1.Substring(0, i) + "!" + ex1.Substring(i+"!".Length());

Answer (score 0):

`String.Replace` does what you want by itself - no need for substring:

```
string output = ex1.Replace("1", "!");
```